# Excel - Counting unique records in a group

Tags: excel

I'm having difficulty counting records in a file that have a unique ID and listing the number of rows associated with that specific ID.

For this file, the unique ID represents a specific family (column A). Each member of the family is in a different row with the same ID.  I would like to count the number of family members(rows) in each unique family.  I can have a few thousand rows so automating this would be wonderful.  Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this now automatically with Excel 2013.

If you have that version, then select your data to create a pivot table, and when you create your table, make sure the option 'Add this data to the Data Model' tickbox is check (see below).

[image: Tick the box next to 'Add this data to the Data Model']

Then, when your pivot table opens, create your rows, columns and values normally. Then click the field you want to calculate the distinct count of and edit the Field Value Settings:
[image: Edit field value settings]

Finally, scroll down to the very last option and choose 'Distinct Count.' 
[image: Choose the option 'Distinct Count']

This should update your pivot table values to show the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm understanding you correctly, you have something like

```
A        B        C         
Fam. ID  LastName FirstName
1        Smith    John
1        Smith    Mary
1        Smith    Johnnie Jr
2        Roe      Rick
3        Doe      Jane
3        Doe      Sam
```

and you want a new column (say, D), with a count of members per family:

```
A        B        C            D       
Fam. ID  LastName FirstName    Fam. Cnt
1        Smith    John         3
1        Smith    Mary         3
1        Smith    Johnnie Jr   3
2        Roe      Rick         1
3        Doe      Jane         2
3        Doe      Sam          2
```

This will do it -- insert at D2 and drag down:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Comment: Yes it does look like that, however is there a way to only the count once per family.  That is where I'm hung up.

Comment: I meant to only show the count once for the smith family.  I will then want to count up how many 1 person families, 2 person families, etc.

Comment: @Syd With this answer as an example, if your Fam Id's are in order simply add the countif into an if statement comparing current fam id with next fam id. For example `=If(A2<>A3, COUNTIF(A:A,A2), "")`. This will result in only the last occurance of a fam id to have the count.