# Excel - count uniques in a range based on another field

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a situation similar to [Excel - Counting unique records in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436293/excel-counting-unique-records-in-a-group) but with a final twist that's giving me a headache.

This is basically how my data looks:

```
A   B   C
--- --- ---
1   5   2   
1   6   2  
1   5   2  
2   7   1  
2   7   1  
2   7   1  
3   8   1  
3   8   1
```

I'm trying to generate the value in column C. I need to count the number of unique values in column B for each different value in column A. Column A is sorted so that all of the values are together.

I've tried this:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$A2, $B$2:$B$1638,"<>"&"")
```

That gives me a count of the number of values in the group, but not the number of *unique* values in the group (so, in my example, it would 3, 3, and 2). I've also tried a pretty cool trick I found on [this page](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif) which counts all of the unique values in the entire column (so in my example, it would be 4 all the way down). I can't figure out how to split the difference.

I've also tried to figure out if it can be done using the IF function, bu I'm coming up dry on that too. Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula in cell D2:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY( IF( $A$2:$A$9=A2, MATCH($B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9,0)), ROW( $B$2:$B$9)-ROW( $B$2)+1)>0))
```

Put this in the formula bar and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (instead of just ENTER) to save it as an array formula.  Excel with place these brackets { } around your formula.

Then copy it down.  It works well, just be aware that array formulas can get very slow if you use thousands of them in a workbook.

I found this following a link to [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) from the "cool trick" you linked to.

If it works let me know, and don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.  Good luck!

Comment: CORRECTION:  Use CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to save it as an array formula.

Comment: I think this may be on the right track, but it doesn't give me exactly what I want. I get this in the C column:

    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, #N/A

instead of the expected:

    2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

I'm going to see what I can learn from this approach - it may ultimately get be where I need to be.